# Vagrant, Virtualbox: Provider 'virtualbox' not found. We'll automatically install it now

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I am running `vagrant up` command on Windows 7 box (`Vagrantfile` exists in work dir) and getting the message:

> Provider 'virtualbox' not found. We'll automatically install it now...

Virtual box has been installed and `vbox_install_path` env variable is correctly set.

Working in intranet, there is no way to automatically install VB from the internet.

Answer (score 9):

Vagrant 1.8.4 and older are [not compatible](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7578) with the VirtualBox 5.1.x.

[Vagrant 1.8.5 has been released](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html) already and it supports the VirtualBox 5.1.x.

Comment: I can confirm that Vagrant 1.8.5 works with VirtualBox 5.1 (5.1.4)

Comment: At this moment Vagrant 1.8.6 works with VirtualBox 5.1.8 r111374

Comment: @pierrebonbon Of course, it should work. As I wrote only Vagrant 1.8.4 and older wasn't compatible with the VirtualBox 5.1.x versions.

Answer (score 8):

Sorted out. Vagrant 1.8.4 does not work with VirtualBox 5.1.0 (on Win7 at least). Fixed after VB version was changed to 5.0.20

Comment: Vagrant 1.8.4 does not work with VirtualBox 5.1.0 on ubuntu either

Comment: The version information should be part of the question, not the answer, since it's one of the most important information for such type of the question.

Comment: what do you mean by "fixed after VB version was changed to 5.0.20'，I thought virtualbox 5.0.20 is older than vurtualbox 5.1.0

Comment: you are right. we downgraded our VB version to 5.0.20